# How to display multiple Tiles dynamically Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface

I have to display multiple tiles on the same screen. Each Tile contains header,contents, and footer that would be set dynamically. So each Tile would be display with dynamic data.
How can I develop a program in android SDK for TABLETs

Comment: Stackoverflow is for specific programming questions. Yours is vague and obviously un-researched. You might want to start buy ordering some Android development books or searching around the web for instructional videos and other content, then come back here when you're stuck on a specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

Just to get you started, you could have a look at [Fragments](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html) (and [Activity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html)'s) or perhaps even a [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html).

All these tips require a certain base knowledge on Android, though, just as @aneal commented on your question.